# factoring out a common term from a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say I have a large determinant with scalar elements:

$$\begin{vmatrix} x\cdot a & x\cdot b & x\cdot c & x\cdot d \\ x\cdot e & x\cdot f & x\cdot g & x\cdot h \\ x\cdot i & x\cdot g & x\cdot k & x\cdot l \\ x\cdot m & x\cdot n & x\cdot o & x\cdot p\end{vmatrix}$$

Is it valid to factor out a term that's common to every element of the determinant?  Is the following true:

$$\begin{vmatrix} x\cdot a & x\cdot b & x\cdot c & x\cdot d \\ x\cdot e & x\cdot f & x\cdot g & x\cdot h \\ x\cdot i & x\cdot g & x\cdot k & x\cdot l \\ x\cdot m & x\cdot n & x\cdot o & x\cdot p\end{vmatrix} = x \cdot \begin{vmatrix} a & b & c & d \\ e & f & g & h \\ i & g & k & l \\ m & n & o & p\end{vmatrix}$$

Comment: A $4\times 4$ determinant is $4$-linear w.r.t. its rows (or its columns), hence the factor should be $x^4$.

Comment: $|kA|=k^n |A|~~~\text{where n= number of rows in matrix A}$

Answer (score 1):

You are almost correct; in the factored expression $x$ should be $x^4$. In general, multiplying any *one* row of a matrix by $k$ multiplies the determinant by $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Determinant is linearly dependent on each row.  So the factor is $x^n$ because every row can be factored out by x.